# gulpfile.js 4 infinity loop

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I'm using gulp version 4, and I'm having problem with infinity loop of the javascript task. I don't really understand what is causing the loop.

```js
// JS
function javascript() {
  return gulp
      .src([paths.js, paths.excludeJS.minJs, paths.excludeJS.underscored], {base: "./"})
      .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
      .pipe(include({
        includePaths: [paths.source]
      }))
      .pipe(babel())
      .pipe(ignore.include(paths.excludeJS.underscored))
      .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.basename += ".min";
        path.extname = ".js";
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
}

exports.default = watch;
exports.js = javascript;
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding to the watch function ignored paths

```js
function watch(){
    gulp.watch(paths.sass, style);
    gulp.watch([paths.js, paths.excludeJS.minJs, paths.excludeJS.underscored], javascript);
}
```